# Seems like I have lots of space outside of the boot disk but I can't install packages - how do I clear space? Ubuntu GCloud VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, filesystems, google-compute-engine

Here is the output of ***`df -H`***. I keep deleting caches and tmp directories but the problem keeps resurfacing. Any tips on how I might clear out more space?

My home directory is only taking up 3GB - including Python packages and so on, not sure where the 104GB is being taken up. I deleted `snapd` earlier because all the loop devices were full with vnode tables; any time I try to install a package, for instance, `xdiskusage`, I get the error `

> After this operation, 525 MB of additional disk space will be used.
> E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/...

```
df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       104G  104G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        180G     0  180G   0% /dev
tmpfs           180G     0  180G   0% /dev/shm 
tmpfs            36G  3.6G   33G  10% /run 
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock 
tmpfs           180G     0  180G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      110M  5.5M  104M   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs            36G     0   36G   0% /run/user/2002
```

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

Warning: you will not be able to log in to Linux when you run out of free disk space. Immediately delete some files or reside the disk larger.

The first step is to delete everything in the /tmp folder. Ignore warnings about not being able to delete files as some processes may have files open.

Next figure out what are the largest files and review which ones can be deleted.

This command will list the 25 largest files:

```
find / -type f -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -25
```

Be careful what you delete. Do not manually delete files located in the OS directories.

Next list the largest installed packages. Uninstall any that are not required.

```
dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -rh | head -25 | awk '{print $1/1024, $2}'
```

Another item is to review the largest directories on your system:

```
du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 25
```

The final solution(s) are up to you. You must decide which files are not longer required for your system.